# How to get record in string format from socketTextStream

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to get each record from the socket stream. I want the record to be a string data type from lines. How to write the code in python? Thanks!

```
model = pipeline.PipelineModel.read().load(model_path)

sc = spark.sparkContext
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

lines = ssc.socketTextStream(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))

if (lines is not None):
       lines.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.foreach(processRecord))

def processRecord(record):

     print("test")
     ...
```

Comment: function processRecord called before assignment.

Answer (score 1):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="Demo")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

    #record = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
    record = ssc.socketTextStream(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))
    # print out each single word
    record.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).pprint()

    # start streaming
    ssc.start()
    # stop when the socket we are listening is dead
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Thanks.

Comment: record is not string type

Comment: I added more codes there. pls check what's wrong with my codes. Thanks!